# How to speed up aggregation of large arrays for many document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

#### Summary

I have hourly data (10 years worth = 87600 hours) for 5 million users, e.g. the number of clicks for each user during each hour. I'm attempting to aggregate in order to get the total number of clicks (across all users) for each hour, but it is very slow (more than 5 days).

#### Non-technical explanation

The data for my problem originates in Pandas. Each user is identified by a `User_ID` and has several pieces of information associated to it. For illustration purposes, I'll consider the user with `User_ID` 15512. One thing I have is a `User_Views` DataFrame with two columns:

```
Hour     Views
-----   ------
11           5
15512       11
82215        2
```

where `Hour` is counted from a fixed start date (January 1st 2008). Only hours where users had non-zero `Views` are included in this table. Unfortunately the DataFrame contains over 80,000 rows for most users.

A second piece of data is the `User_Clicks` DataFrame with the hourly number of clicks for each user:

```
Hour     Clicks
-----   ------
5511         1
34412        3
51241        2
66615       10
```

I want to aggregate the `Views` across all users in order to get a total number of Views (across all users) for each Hour. I wish to do the same for the `Clicks`.

#### Technical explanation

To this end, I have stored the data above into MongoDB using the following schema:

```
schema = [
    {
        'User_ID': 15512,
        'User_Name': 'Jack Daniels',
        'Information_Type': 'Views',
        'User_Views': [
            {'Hour': 11, 'Views': 5},
            {'Hour': 15512, 'Views': 11},
            {'Hour': 82215, 'Views': 2},
        ]
    },
    {
        'User_ID': 15512,
        'User_Name': 'Jack Daniels',
        'Information_Type': 'Clicks',
        'User_Clicks': [
            {'Hour': 5511, 'Clicks': 1},
            {'Hour': 34412, 'Clicks': 3},
            {'Hour': 51241, 'Clicks': 2},
            {'Hour': 66615, 'Clicks': 10},
        ]
    },
    # The above is then repeated for every User_ID.
]
```

In order to get `User_Views` in the schema, I did `df.to_dict(orient='records')` on the `User_Views` DataFrame in Python. Similarly for `User_Clicks`.

Ideally I have `User_Clicks` and `User_Views` live in the same document, but I could not get an aggregation to work quickly for that setup so I have split Clicks from Views as seen in the schema above.

I have indexed over `Information_Type`. I have set `allowDiskUse=True`.

The pipeline I'm using to aggregate Views is:

```
pipeline = [
    # Get only Views documents
    {"$match": {"Information_Type": "Views"}},  

    # Return only Hours and Views
    {"$project": {"User_Views.Hour": 1, "User_Views.Views": 1}},   

    # Unwind/flatten User_Views, since it's an array of documents         
    {"$unwind": "$User_Views"},      

    # Group by Hour across all documents and sum the Views          
    {"$group": {"_id": "$User_Views.Hour", "Total_Views": {"$sum": "$User_Views.Views"}}}
```

Similarly for Clicks.

#### Problem and goals

The runtime for 5 million users and 87600 hours for the pipeline above is approximately a week at this time.

I'm trying to do two things:

1) reduce the runtime by gaining insight on improvements to the schema and pipeline,

2) ideally using schema where Views and Clicks are not split across two documents for each user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you simply can't get through 5mm users X 87600 pieces of data fast enough through a single pipeline.  Databases (most of them) are great when indexes can be used to find relatively small subsets of the population.  They are not as good when you want to look at *all* the data.  This problem does have a map/reduce feel to it.

But in MongoDB, a way to do this is by threading and using multiple queries working at the same time.  Each thread gets a range of `Hour`, e.g. in pseudo code:

```
nthreads = 20
incr = 87600 / nthreads 
curr = 0
while nthreads > 0:
    exec_query (curr, curr+incr)
    curr += incr
    nthreads--

exec_query(start, end):
   spawn{
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {'Information_Type': 'Views'}}

,{$project: {X: {$filter: {
        input: "$User_Views",
        as: "zz",
        cond: {$and:[
{$gte: ['$$zz.Hour', start]}
,{$lt: ['$$zz.Hour', end]}
                     ]
                }
            }}
    }}

,{$unwind: "$X"}
,{$group: {_id:"$X.Hour", total: {$sum: "$X.Views"} }}
]);
```

There will be a lot of reading of data, yes, and the `$filter` operator ends up tossing a lot of data but you'll get more `$group` operations running in parallel.